# Why isn't the `flat rate scheme` favourable for Limited Companies anymore?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, self-employment, vat

I have been registered as flat rate scheme since 2012. At which point I kept 12.5% (working in IT) of my vat invoices.

However in 2017 they changed the laws on the % I believe.

My accountant said I shouldn't be on the flat rate anymore and I'm wondering why its still not viable?

Comment: Have you asked your accountant why they've said that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2017, the rate for businesses/sole traders that spend <2% of their income on goods [changed to 16.5%](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-38084493), probably because the government felt the 12.5% was giving too much of an advantage.

16.5% is only a tiny amount less than the "normal" VAT rate, as it's calculated on the total invoice amount - for an invoice with a base cost of £100+20% VAT, you'd bring in £120 and pay out £19.80 to the government. If you used standard VAT accounting, then you'd pay out £20 to the government and be able to reclaim VAT on any goods you did buy as part of the business. If more than 1% of your income is going on goods, you'd be better off with the standard approach.

Comment: So with the 16.5% I'd be keeping 3.5% of the VAT money, so with £100 wouldn't it be £3.5? I think this is the part that I find the most confusing.

Comment: @JamieHutber No, because it's 16.5% of the *total* invoice, including VAT. On the same calculation, normal VAT is 1/6th = 16.666% of the total invoice, because £20 of a £120 invoice is VAT.

Comment: Ahhh this does make sense now my friend :) Thank you.