# What's the point of a 20% (alias 16.5%) VAT flat rate in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-deduction, vat

The normal VAT in UK is already 20%.

Note that 16.5% VAT flat rate for £100 is not £16.5 but £20.0. HMRC does not calculate like any other country I know. The 16.5% is calculated on the invoiced gross amount including the normal VAT. 16.5% of £120 is £20 (or £19.8 calculating with double precision)

Comment: Taxes raise revenue for the government. The precise rate and structure of the tax are a matter of economic modelling and political haggling.

Comment: I considered closing this as a duplicate of https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102676/why-isnt-the-flat-rate-scheme-favourable-for-limited-companies-anymore?rq=1, as it contains mostly the same information, but it's a different perspective so in the end I didn't.

Comment: I see, the answer is the same hence I am ok with you marking this as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 16.5% rate applies to businesses that spend [less than 2% of their turnover, or less than £1,000 on goods](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-38084493). It was raised in 2017, probably because the normal flat rates are too favourable for such businesses.

As you say, the precise calculation gives £19.80, so it's still marginally favourable if total costs are less than 1%. Or people might choose it to limit their administrative effort, even though they lose out slightly in actual tax paid.

Comment: If you earn £100k and spend £900, you save £20 with the flat rate. Not worth a dedicated law. But I see your point regarding less administration if you spend below 2% (very roughly)

Comment: @PennyFox It's not really a dedicated law, more of a tweak to the existing law on flat rates, as a way of reducing the benefit/discouraging certain people to use them.